# HTTPHandlers\Modules in SharePoint 2013 to deal with request errors

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, error-handling, exception-handling

I am currently trying my best to implement a Handler to redirect error pages on Sharepoint 2013.

Our project has a bunch of webparts that are inside pages - and when these webparts reach certain exceptions, they direct to different error pages based on the HTTP Status Code (a 404 page for not found resources, a 500 page for generic errors, and so on).

This all begun when we tried to use the custom pages with the [Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607768.aspx). It did not work, mainly because of an [bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2b6ee114-8e49-4bee-9de8-22ebfbdd29d7/cant-change-custom-layout-pages-through-setspcustomlayoutspage-powershell-cmd?forum=sharepointdevelopment) found in the SharePoint 2013 core.

So, we've tried a lot of alternatives:

- [Adding And Deploying Generic Handlers (.Ashx) To A SharePoint 2010 Visual Studio Project](http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/adding-and-deploying-generic-handlers-ashx-to-a-sharepoint-2010-visual-studio-project/)
- [How to Create a Custom Exception Error Page in Sharepoint](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ManasMoharana/how-to-create-a-custom-exception-error-page-in-sharepoint/)
- [Custom Errors and SharePoint 2010](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2011/6/14/custom_errors_and_sharepoint_2010)
- [Adding And Deploying Generic Handlers (.Ashx) To A SharePoint 2013 Visual Studio Project](http://peakfinders.blogspot.com.br/2015/03/adding-and-deploying-generic-handlers.html)

And the list goes on. Nothing worked. And we can't update with the cumulative update right now to fix the SPCustomLayoutPages because how the version works on the side of our client - if we update it, we would need to update on the client side as well - but that's not possible at the current moment.

We've then decided to make a handler to use it to deal with all the requests, but I can't see to make it work in any way on Sharepoint 2013, even with through research.

So, how to make this handler work? How to make a generic handler that can treat all exceptions in Sharepoint and redirect as needed? And how to deploy and configure it correctly?